# why does range-v3 yield require default constructor

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to understand, for what reasons does the yield family of functions require that class be default constructible?

In the following example, the vnums1 line compiles only if CNum has a default constructor. The vnums2 line does not require a default constructor.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Range-V3-VS2015. Thank you!

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

struct CNum
{
    // CNum() = default;
    explicit CNum(int num) : m_num(num) {}
    int m_num;
};

int main()
{
    auto ints = ranges::view::ints(0, 10);

    // this compiles only of CNum has a default constructor
    auto vnums1 = ints
        | ranges::view::for_each([](int num) { return ranges::yield_if(num % 2, CNum(num)); })
        | ranges::to_vector;

    // this compiles even if CNum does not have a default constructor
    auto vnums2 = ints
        | ranges::view::remove_if([](int num) { return num % 2 == 0; })
        | ranges::view::transform([](int num) { return CNum(num); })
        | ranges::to_vector;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just changed the code to not require DefaultConstructible. git pull and enjoy.

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

Maintainers of Microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015 are not picking up new changes from ericniebler/range-v3. Does anybody have suggestions on how I can go about getting the latest bits to work with VC++ 2017?

Comment: Sadly, your best bet is to fork the Microsoft/Range-V3-VS2015 repo and make the changes yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to default constructor to use `ranges::yield_if` is that the machinery it uses requires the type to be default constructable.  If we look at the code we have

```
struct yield_if_fn
{
    template<typename V>
    repeat_n_view<V> operator()(bool b, V v) const
    {
        return view::repeat_n(std::move(v), b ? 1 : 0);
    }
};

/// \relates yield_if_fn
/// \ingroup group-views
RANGES_INLINE_VARIABLE(yield_if_fn, yield_if)
```

And we can see that it calls `view::repeat_n`.  Looking at that code we get

```
repeat_n_view<Val> operator()(Val value, std::ptrdiff_t n) const
{
    return repeat_n_view<Val>{std::move(value), n};
}
```

And if we look at `repeat_n_view` we have

```
// Ordinarily, a view shouldn't contain its elements. This is so that copying
// and assigning ranges is O(1), and also so that in the event of element
// mutation, all the copies of the range see the mutation the same way. The
// repeat_n_view *does* own its lone element, though. This is OK because:
//  - O(N) copying is fine when N==1 as it is in this case, and
//  - The element is immutable, so there is no potential for incorrect
//    semantics.

struct repeat_n_view
  : view_facade<repeat_n_view<Val>, finite>
{
private:
    friend range_access;
    Val value_;
    std::ptrdiff_t n_;

    // ...
public:
    repeat_n_view() = default;
    constexpr repeat_n_view(Val value, std::ptrdiff_t n)
      : value_(detail::move(value)), n_((RANGES_EXPECT(0 <= n), n))
    {}
    constexpr std::size_t size() const
    {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(n_);
    }
};
```

We see from the comment that this was a design decision and because of this design you need your type to be default constructable.  Eric describes the type required as being `SemiRegular` which is documented as

> it needs to be default constructable, copy and move constructable, and destructable.